# How to click on the desired link when there are two distinct links with the same TagName and InnerText using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to get the code in my VBA Module to click on a specific link on a webpage, but there are two distinct links with the same name ("Edit") and I cannot seem to click on the one I want to select (the second of the two).

With the code I currently have, I am able to access the first "Edit" link, but I need to access the second "Edit" link instead.

Here is what I currently have:

```
   Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks

            If hyper_link.innerText = "Edit" Then
                hyper_link.Click
                Exit For

            End If
        Next
```

The links appear in the page source as follows:

First "Edit" link

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$esbasegrid_$ctl02$ctl00','')">Edit</a>
```

Second "Edit" link (***the one I want to click on***)

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl04$ctl00$ctl01$esbasegrid_$ctl02$ctl00','')">Edit</a>
```

As I have indicated above, I would like to get to click on the second "Edit" link, but instead my code is clicking on the first.

Relatively new to VBA, so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    Dim i As Long
    Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
       Debug.Print "Link", hyper_link.innerText
       If hyper_link.innerText = "Edit" Then
            i = i + 1
            Debug.Print , "Edit Link #" & i
            If i = 2 Then
                Debug.Print , "Clicking...!"
                hyper_link.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I think I get what your additions are supposed to do here, but instead of getting me to through the first "Edit" link, I'm just staying on the same page with both "Edit" links now with no error messages provided.

Comment: Then maybe there aren't two links with "Edit" when you code runs? Perhaps a timing issue - if you put a break on the "Set.." line and wait a couple of seconds before continuing does it then work?

Comment: I already have a break specified just before I run that chunk, so both "Edit" are definitely on the webpage.  I tried adding one in on the "Set..." line, but got an error saying "permission denied"

Comment: Try adding some debugging output (see edits above) - do you get what you expect?

Comment: Still no difference.  Is there a way to reference the href value instead of the innerText value?  If so, that would solve the problem.  Your attention here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "no difference" means what ? - what output do you see in the Immediate pane in the VB editor?

Comment: The output in the immediate pane lists 50+ links, showing things like `Link          State Licenses:` (which is the link I clicked on earlier in my code by using getElementByID and is the page on which I'm trying to select the second 'Edit' link).  There was no `Link          Edit` printed in the immediate pane.  Apologies for any lack of clarity.

Comment: Well if there are no "Edit" links on the page then it's difficult to make any suggestions as to how you can fix that.  Maybe if you also show the code that gets you to that page there might be something there to work with.

Comment: I extended the delay by a few seconds and the print commands returned what would be expected.  Took out the print lines from the code (used the code you originally provided) and everything worked as expected.  This has been enormously helpful, thank you for your patience and willingness to help